# Joomla> Selected Drop Down Not passing to Server

Tags: php, joomla, html-select

I know I am missing something basic here, but for the life of me, I cannot figure this out.

I need the hidden input field to reflect the course selected by the user in the drop down.

=====================================================================

```
<p><b>1. Select Course:</b></p>
<?php

$db = JFactory :: getDBO();
$query = "select name from #__guru_category  order by name ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();
$options = array(); 
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option','Select Course');
foreach($result as $row)
{
$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row->name);
}
$dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'class="inputbox"', 'subject', 'value', 'text');
echo $dropdown; 

?>
<p><b>2. Select assignment file to upload:</b></p>
<p><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
**<input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" value="">**
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload Assignment File" name="submit"></p>

</form>
```

====================================================

Comment: And what do you get what you echo $dropdown?  Right now this code sets the value to `""`  what else have you tried?  Why is the type hidden if the user is supposed to select?

Comment: The hidden value should return the name of the course selected by the  user..

Comment: I asked what *do* you get no what *should* you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options, 'class="inputbox"', 'subject', 'value', 'text');
```

**You have missplaced the argument value orderlist**

```
genericlist($arr, $name, $attribs=null, $key= 'value', $text= 'text', $selected=NULL, $idtag=false, $translate=false)
```

folow the link:
https://docs.joomla.org/API15:JHTMLSelect/genericlist

**Here the solution**

```
<?php
$db = JFactory :: getDBO();
$query = "select name from #__guru_category  order by name ASC";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadObjectList();

$options = array(); 
$attr  = 'onchange="UpdateUsername(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"';
$attr .= ' class="inputbox"';

$options[] = JHTML::_('select.option','Select Course');
foreach($result as $row){
    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.option', $row->name);
}
$dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist', $options,'subject',$attr, 'value', 'text');
echo $dropdown; 

?>
<p><b>2. Select assignment file to upload:</b></p>
<p><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" value="">
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload Assignment File" name="submit"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateUsername(selected){
 document.getElementById(subject).value= selected;  
}
</script>
```

Comment: What must I enter in the " " in the hidden value field? <input type="hidden" name="subject" id="subject" value=" ??? ">

Comment: You have chosen a value will be set automatically.( we have using onchange function "UpdateUsername(selected)" set the selected value)